# error shows up when i add Auth::user()->id

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

this shows up when i add Auth::user()->id :

array_merge(): Expected parameter 2 to be an array, object given

here is the javascript :

```js
var user = {!! empty(Auth::user()->id); !!};
        if (!user) {
            if (tempCart >0) {
                const pid = {!! json_encode($meterai->product_id); !!};
                const baseUrl = window.location.origin
                const url = baseUrl+"/"+pid+"/"+qty
                console.log(url)

            }else{
                alert("anda belum menentukan kuantitas meterai")
            }
        }else{
            alert("silahkan login terlebih dahulu untuk menambah keranjang")
        }
```

Here is the Controller :

```php
public function index()
    {
        $this->login();
        
        if (!empty(Auth::user()->id))
            $data = $this->getPageData(Auth::user()->id);
        else
            $data = $this->getPageData(null);

        return view ('emeterai',$data);
    }
```

[image: here is the error]

Comment: I think ```$mergeData``` or ```$this->parseData($data)``` is returning ```object```

Comment: where is $mergeData and $this->parseData($data) ? and is it fixable? even if i only put Auth::user()->id on variable it shows that error

Comment: What is on line 91 of your `EMeteriaController`? Please add the relevant function code to your question.

Comment: This is the only line that runs php code in the code you show `var user = {!! empty(Auth::user()->id); !!};` so (apart from not having a clue what is this supposed to achieve) you perhaps have an error somewhere else that is impacting authentication

Comment: i edited the post, included the controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while returning to a view the view method accepts 2 parameters  1st is view name and second is variable/data.  so in your case 2nd parameter syntax is wrong. It should be as following :

```
public function index()
    {
        $this->login();
        
        if (!empty(Auth::user()->id))
            $data = $this->getPageData(Auth::user()->id);
        else
            $data = $this->getPageData(null);

             return view ('path.to.the.balde.file',compact('data'));

        return view ('emeterai',compact('data'));
    }
```